# AS3 text and textbox width

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text, textbox, width

I have a dynamic alert method that pops up an alert movieclip which tells the user that their search was not successful.

```
alert("Map [" + inputTxt + "] not found.");
```

Now, I would like to do something along the lines of

```
if (alertText.textWidth > myText.text.width) {
    myText.text = "Map not found.";
}
```

What this is supposed to do is not show the inputTxt variable if the total text in the textbox exceeds the textbox itself in size.

That which I have does not work. I am open to any suggestions (as long as they remain short and concise).

FURTHER INFORMATION:
alertText is the string fed into the object. myText.text is a textbox.
I want to check if alertText will fit in myText.text BEFORE putting it in the textbox.

-Olin

Comment: Are `alertText` and `myText.text` both `TextField`s?  how do they relate to each other that requires you to compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a string does not have a textWidth property.  There is no (easy) way to know ahead of time if your text will fit, unless your using a font where every char is the same width.

Here is a way to accomplish this:

```
myText.text = alertText; //put the text in the box

if(myText.textHeight > myText.height || myText.textWidth > myText.width){
    //the text does not fit in it's entirety.
    myText.text = "Map not found.";
}
```

This assumes your not using the `autoSize` property of the textField and are explicitly settings the width/height.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why I didn't do this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check string before assiging it to destination textfield, you can create another and use its textFormat

```
var someShortText : String = "short string";
var someLongText : String = "very, very, very, very, long text";

function checkStringWidth(string : String, tMaxWidth : Number, tFormat : TextFormat) : Boolean {
    var tField : TextField = new TextField();
    tField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    tField.multiline = false;
    tField.wordWrap = false;
    tField.defaultTextFormat = tFormat;
    tField.text = string;
    return tField.width<=tMaxWidth;
}

trace(checkStringWidth(someShortText, someTF.width, someTF.defaultTextFormat));         
trace(checkStringWidth(someLongText , someTF.width, someTF.defaultTextFormat));
```